# SMTP in Laravel 7 godaddy hosting

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-7

So i have created an App in Laravel 7 and Deployed it in Godaddy Shared hosting, everything works except for the Mailing.

This is the .env values

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=email@outlook.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=TLS
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=email@outlook.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="YourName"
```

and the value in config/mail.php
`'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp')`

This is working Perfectly in Localhost, but when i deployed to goDaddy shared hosting, this doesnt seems to work.
I have tried changing the value to .env value to `MAIL_MAILER=sendmail` and congif/mail.php to `'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'sendmail')`

This doesnt show any error, also displayed to Success Message. but Mail not being sent.
What is the Fix ?

Comment: Does `php artisan config:cache` fix it? Hope you have SSH access.

Comment: Nope, ```php artisan config:cache``` that doesnt fix

Comment: Does your env() get the correct value? Have you checked your spam folders?

Comment: You need to catch the error, otherwise you wont see any error message.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that GoDaddy blocks SMTP ports to avoid the usage of third-party SMTP services [[1]](https://my.godaddy.com/help/send-form-mail-using-an-smtp-relay-server-953) [[2]](https://my.godaddy.com/community/Using-WordPress/Connection-Refused-for-GMail-SMTP/m-p/132046#M8870). In order to send emails, GoDaddy says to use their [SMTP relay server](https://my.godaddy.com/help/send-form-mail-using-an-smtp-relay-server-953), which requires no authentication. So your env would look like:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=relay-hosting.secureserver.net
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=email@yourgodaddydomain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="YourName"
```

Emails from shared hosts are highly likely to be blacklisted by most servers.

Your next option would be to use an email API such as [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/) or [Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/) (there are other providers too of cause). Both of them have a free plan which has a limited quota so you can try.

Finally, your last resort would be to ditch GoDaddy (I never liked them anyway) and move to another host provider. I suggest [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) (ask me for referral link to get $25 ) or [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/).

Comment: This method works but it need to add the MAIL_USERNAME and MAIL_PASSWORD.

Answer (score 1):

Change your .env

`MAIL_MAILER=smtp`
`MAIL_HOST=localhost`
`MAIL_PORT=25`
`MAIL_USERNAME=null`
`MAIL_PASSWORD=null`
`MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null`
`MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=no-reply@your_godaddy_domain.com`
`MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"`